# Restarted my computer and suddenly git is not working

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

-bash: /Users/winchenzo/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory

-bash: /Users/winchenzo/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory

-bash: __git_ps1: command not found

Also I get this after every normal terminal command I run. I'm using the latest 2015 macbook pro with el capitan installed, but it was working fine with el capitan for weeks ( installed el capitan as soon as i came out weeks ago)

-bash: __git_ps1: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Update your path to include where you installed the files `git-completion.bash` and `git-prompt.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

in my bash prof I did this

```
source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
```

and it works again, nice

Comment: A better solution is to put those lines in `.bashrc`, then make sure `.bashrc` is sourced from `.bash_profile`. Both lines contain code that is useful for *any* interactive shell, not just login shells.